# Comparing frequency of word use across Shakespeare's plays

Tags: william-shakespeare, wording-choice

There are numerous concordances that list all of the words, and their frequency of use within each of Shakespeare's plays. However, I am interested in the presence and frequency of use of words *across* those plays.

For example, I would like to compare the frequency of the term *beauty* in "Hamlet" with its use in "The Tempest."

While this can be done manually by looking up the instance in the separate concordances of each of the plays, is there a project or program that does this for all of the plays (or some subset of them)?

Answer (score 8):

I have used this in the past: [Open Source Shakespeare: Concordance
of Shakespeare's complete works](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/concordance/). For example, you can type “beauty” into the box and get [this page](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/concordance/o/?i=763867&pleasewait=1&msg=sr) that shows the occurrences in each work. Here's *Hamlet* to *The Tempest*, showing that there are [5 occurrences](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=hamlet&keyword1=beauty&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr) in *Hamlet* and [2 occurrences](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=tempest&keyword1=beauty&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr) in *The Tempest*:

[image: output]

(In this case there seems to be a bug—after clicking on *Tempest* I see just one result—so I'd prefer to download data and write a program myself... but this may be useful to you as a start, and you can report a bug to the site owners.)

Answer (score 0):

The Folger Shakespeare Library's [Miranda Digital Asset Platform](https://www.folger.edu/online-resources/digital-asset-platform) is due for launch and release in the fall of 2018. As stated on their website the goal is to "build a full digital asset platform".

A digital analysis of Shakespeare's plays using off-the-shelf plagiarism software was recently published that may offer a more immediate answer to your query: ["Plagiarism Software Unveils a New Source for 11 of Shakespeare’s Plays"](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/07/books/plagiarism-software-unveils-a-new-source-for-11-of-shakespeares-plays.html) (by Michael Blanding,*The New York Times*, 7 February 2018).